# Multiple js files in code playground

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to create app like JSfiddle but with support of multiple files, like in codesandbox. I’ll create folder tree like below. but how to use it in import statement (import a from ‘./a.js’) should I parse js file to extract path from import and get content along this path (node value), or what?

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data:
  {
    value: '',
    tree: [
      {
        label: 'Root',
        value: 'root',
        nodes: [
          {
            label: 'Child with children',
            value: 'child_parent',
            nodes: [
              {
                label: 'Child from child',
                value: 999
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            label: 'Child lonewolf',
            value: -10
          }
        ],
      }
    ],
  }
});
```

Comment: Umm... Not sure what "support of multiply files" means, but JSFiddle supports multiple files of any type...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan in jsfiddle there are only one js file, css, html, but I want to create navigation menu with tree folders, js files, like here https://codesandbox.io/s/vue?from-embed

Comment: There are only one of the JS/CSS/HTML editable areas, but you can add as many external files as you want.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan yes, but I need more, like in codesandbox, it's like online idea with possibility add dependencies

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [codesandbox.io](http://codesandbox.io). When you create a sandbox, you get the ability to add multiple files.

[image: codesandbox ide]

As you can see in my example, I was able to create the file a.js by clicking the New File icon.